# How can I mention that a question has arisen from a previously asked question?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I was asking a question on math.SE and therein I wanted to mention that the **question has arisen from a previously asked question**.

I want to not write it that way but using a word that is better than (**more apt than**) "**follow-up**" question. As follow-up question takes in more clarification/explanation for the previously asked question.

But in my case, the resolution of the previous question has given "birth" to the new question. So, maybe "**baby question**" but putting this too **doesn't feel right**.

(Note: I have included both [word-choice] and [phrase-request] as I don't know which one would be fit/more suitable to my case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to mention that the question has arisen from a previously asked question.

You used *arisen* above. That's absolutely correct. Anything can *raise* a question.

So we could say:

> My earlier question **raises** another question

or

> I have a second question - **raised** by the question before.

---

If you're looking for a single adjective, you could also say:

- I have a **further** question

which subtly suggests that the new question may be associated with and / or originate from the question before (though, it may be unconnected).

Comment: Thank you! I'll make-do with this. Honestly, I was looking for a better *word* that would capture my intentions but until nothing else shows up, your answer looks quite convincing to me. Upvoted.

Comment: "further" works very well.